# Member functions same as passing reference to global function?

Tags: c++, function, methods

Can I be sure that:

```
class foo {
  public:
  int x;
  void bar(int k) {
    x = k;
  }
};
foo o;
o.bar(5);
```

Will be the same as:

```
class foo {
  public:
  int x;
};

void foobar(foo& f, int k) {
  f.x = k;
}

foo o;
foobar(o, 5);
```

I know both will set "x" to "k", but can I be sure that they both perform at same speed / generate same asm? Can the compiler optimize methods greater?

Comment: @KennyCason: That may be true, but I would not want him to accept answers purely to increase some meaningless statistic as you encourage.

Comment: fair enough, but what are the odds of 75% of his questions asked not having decent acceptable answers? :P

Comment: @Kenny: Honestly I could not care much, as long as the question is interesting to me, I'll take the time to read it and its answers, and (if I am in the mood) perhaps even throw in some answer of mine. I don't understand while people are fixating on that "Accept Rate" parameter...

Comment: @Matthieu I agree, If it's a cool question (and I know the answer) I'd still answer it. I definitely was interested in this question actually. I guess it's the whole thing of asking questions but not giving any feedback is a bit rude and kind of goes against SO, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know both will set "x" to "k", but can I be sure that they both perform at same speed / generate same asm?

Practically, you can be sure it doesn't matter.  If you think it matters, then profile and compare the differences, or look at asm output from your compiler.

> Can the compiler optimize methods greater?

Generally it cannot.  Especially for short, inline, non-virtual functions as in your example (you need to mark foobar as inline to be exactly equivalent to the first piece of code), the function call in either case is likely to simply disappear.

Comment: As far as I know, the compiler will also likely inline most of short non-inline and even virtual functions (when the actual type is known). Smart beasts those compilers are nowadays :)

Comment: @7vies: True. :)  The primary requirement is either that link-time optimization (or whatever the implementation calls it) is enabled or that the definition is known in that TU.

Comment: marking as inline doesn't mean the compiler will do so. It most likely will with the above function whether you mark it or not.

Comment: @CashCow: Out of functions used in more than one TU, it is only inline functions that are defined in every TU where they are used.  That is the true modern meaning of inline and what I meant.  (I didn't not say the compiler *will always* inline the function call, for example.)

Comment: @Fred Nurk: I'm slightly confused.. Does this mean `static` functions are now called inline too?

Comment: @7vies: If the definition is available (and it will be), then sure, the compiler can do that for global-/namespace-scope static.  It is not required to do so, of course.  (And s/didn't not/didn't/ on my last comment.)

Comment: @Fred Nurk: If I got you right, you are saying that it is going to be *inlined*, but I'm asking if it is *called* "inline", just as you mentioned above "the true modern meaning of inline". Oh, I just realized that I should also underline that by "called" I mean "referred to", not "executed" :D

Comment: @7vies: No, namespace-scope static functions are not referred to as being "inline" (at least not by anyone I know), though they do have internal linkage, which is similar.  By "the true modern meaning of inline" I meant the *keyword* rather than all uses of the word in prose.

Answer (score 3):

Generate the assembler and compare (`-S` flag for GCC).

Comment: I was wondering if it could be different for larger methods, but so far I cam convinced.

Answer (score 2):

In a few cases, it *can* make a difference in the generated assembly code, but (at least usually) not much.

For example, Microsoft's compiler will (normally) use what they call `thiscall` calling convention for member functions, in which case, the `this` pointer is passed in register ECX. Global functions default to the `cdecl` calling convention, in which the parameters are all passed on the stack. It's also possible, however, to tell the compiler to use the `fastcall` calling convention, in which the first two parameters are passed in ECX and EDX respectively (so as long as you pass the imitation-`this` as the first parameter, it ends up the same as `thiscall`).

Years ago (e.g., 286, 386 time-frame), passing parameters in registers instead of on the stack saved quite a bit of time. Now that most CPUs have at least a few megabytes of on-board cache, most of that difference has disappeared.

Comment: Should I tell compiler to use "thiscall" convention with foobar?

Comment: @Pepe: At least AFAIK, while you can specify `__cdecl` or `__fastcall`, there's no matching `__thiscall`. You can only get `thiscall` by default.

Comment: @Pepe: no you shouldn't! Unless you are completely sure it is necessary. It looks like you are trying to do some premature not-even-an-optimization here.

Comment: @7vies actually, I'm already specifying calling convention since I'm using function pointers

Comment: @Pepe: Generally you don't have to specify calling conventions to use function pointers, so I'm not sure if I see what you mean.

Answer (score -2):

The first example has foo::bar in the virtual function table for class foo. The second does not. That makes it a tiny bit more space efficient. Since foobar is not virtual, the compiler can probably do more in the way of optimization.

Comment: Non-virtual methods are not in the vtable.